# Order of DIVs on mobile with ZURB Foundation (Push/Pull)

Tags: css-float, zurb-foundation

Quick question involving foundation. If I want divs to go in order 1 then 2 on desktop and 2 then 1 on mobile, how would I accomplish this using Zurb?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">
    </div>
    <div class="nine columns">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This can definitely be done. In your code you should order the div's based on how you would display it on the mobile, i.e. 2 then 1. For displaying it properly on larger screens you can override the default styling of the div's.

For testing purposes you can try:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="nine columns" style="float:right;">
    </div>
    <div class="three columns" style="float:left;">
    </div>
</div>
```

While the above solution will work, I suggest not using inline styling. I would rather override using custom classes and/or @media tags.

Using those the code would be:

For the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="nine columns pull-right">
    </div>
    <div class="three columns pull-left">
    </div>
</div>
```

For the CSS/Stylesheet:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .pull-left {float: left !important;}
    .pull-right {float: right !important;}
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! I will implement soon and see how I'm sitting, but sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do this strictly with css, but with javascript you can add the pull-x classes when applicable.

theory:
Place the columns in the order you want for the mobile device, or small screens rather. Then in document.ready, check whether show-for-small is visibile or not, if not, you are on a larger screen and can apply push|pull classes to your columns of choice.

pseudo code, assuming you know [push/pull technique](http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/grid.php):

```
// do this if not on small screen
if ( $('.show-on-small').css('display') == 'none' ) {
  // pull or push the columns as needed
  $('.myColumnsToPull-two').addClass('pull-two');
} else {
  // might be a good idea to revert above change
}
```